# Ways to do timeouts in Perl?

Tags: perl, timeout

I frequently use the following pattern to set an upper bound to the running time of a particular code fragment in Perl:

```
my $TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 5;
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" };
    alarm($TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS);
    # do stuff that might timeout.
    alarm(0);
};
if ($@) {
    # handle timeout condition.
}
```

My questions:

- Is this the right way to do it?
- Are there any circumstances under which the running time can exceed $TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS, or is the above method bullet-proof?

Comment: Your eval is vulnerable to a nasty bug.  Read the Try::Tiny docs for a detailed explanation: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Try::Tiny

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably want to look at [Sys::SigAction](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sys::SigAction).  I haven't used it myself, but it has [some glowing reviews](http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/Sys-SigAction).

One thing to watch out for is if "stuff that might timeout" uses `sleep` or `alarm` itself.  Also, in the error handling code, I assume you're prepared for errors other than a timeout.

Comment: could you please explain the case  when the application is using sleep itself? And, how to solve it?

Answer (score 5):

You could also try [Time::Out](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time%3A%3AOut). I like the syntax and nested timeouts are supported..

Comment: +1 This module handles all the worries about nested timeouts etc for you so you don't have to worry about all the edge cases. It is to alarm what try::tiny is to eval.

Comment: Is the Time::Out module threadsafe? In my case I need a timeout running per thread in my application.

Comment: The only problem is that is uses Time::HiRes::alarm which isn't windows compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Take care with signal handling. Perl receives signals asynchronously and they may be lost or interfere with each other if a signal is received while another signal is being handled by the callback.

Event-handling libraries' Win32 support is pretty so-so in Perl (I have to support non-cygwin Win32), so I generally use a simple polling loop for timeouts:

```
use Time::HiRes qw(sleep);

sub timeout {
  my $timeout = shift;
  my $poll_interval = shift;
  my $test_condition = shift;
  until ($test_condition->() || $timeout <= 0) {
    $timeout -= $poll_interval;
    sleep $poll_interval;
  }
  return $timeout > 0; # condition was met before timeout
}

my $success = timeout(30, 0.1, \&some_condition_is_met);
```

The sleep timer can be easily made user- or caller-configurable and unless you are doing an extremely tight loop or have multiple callers waiting on the loop (where you can end up with a race or dead lock), it is a simple, reliable, and cross-platform way to implement a timeout.

Also note that the loop overhead will mean that you cannot guarantee that the timeout is observed absolutely. $test_condition, the decrement, garbage collection, etc. can interfere.

Comment: This does not answer the question. This code won't achieve the same objective as the OP's code. If some_condition_is_met() never returns, the program will hang.