# decrease value of variable with time

Tags: perl

I want to write a script in perl that will define a value for a variable say "10".
Then, it will ask user to enter the value through STDIN for that variable.
If user, enters the value within a fixed TIME INTERVAL, then take that value, else continue the program by taking that default value of 10.

I had no idea how to do that. I thought of some thing like this..
$t=120 (for 120 seconds)
decrease value of "$t" with every second, if user enters some value
then come out of loop, and continue, else when $t becomes 0, take default value and continue.
But, i dont have any idea of how can i decrease value of variable with time along with asking user for input.

I can do this, decrease value of variable with time, but within that, i am not able to take input.

Comment: You should setup a timeout signal. Read this related article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423288/ways-to-do-timeouts-in-perl Regards,

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple example of how you might do it with an alarm signal.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = eval {
    my $tmp;

    # this sub will be called after the timeout set by the alarm below
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
        print "timeout - using default value 10\n";
        $tmp = 10;
    };

    print "enter input: ";
    alarm 10;    # wait for 10 secs
    $tmp = <>;
    alarm 0;     # turn off alarm if we got input within 10 secs
    $tmp;
};

print "the value is: $input\n";
```

Comment: Why is the eval necessary?  Nothing `die()`s.

Comment: That's true; just force-of-habit when writing alarms I guess.

Comment: This doesn't quite work.  Perl will *restart* the interrupted read, meaning a line of input is required to advance execution even after the `alarm()` fires.  (I suspect the reason you `eval`d this "out of habit" is because one correct technique is to `die` in the ALRM handler, avoiding the restart.)  If you set `$tmp` to something other than a number in your ALRM handler (e.g., `$tmp = "timeout"`), you'll see that this techique doesn't work at all.  The reason it appears to work with a numeric assignment is because of a [thorny bug](https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=113906).

Answer (score 1):

You can *also* accomplish this with **IO::Select**

```
use strict;
use IO::Select;

my $value = 10;
my $obj = IO::Select->new(\*STDIN);
foreach my $hand ($obj->can_read(2)) {
    $value = <$hand> ;
}
print "value is :$value:\n" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [Prompt::Timeout](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Prompt%3a%3aTimeout).